# Acceptable consensus set, RANSAC?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, 3d, regression, ransac

The [paper](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~belhumeur/courses/compPhoto/ransac.pdf) of Fischler and Bolles defines 3 unspecified parameters for RANSAC. One of them is

> the threshold t,
>   which is the number of compatible points used to imply
>   that the correct model has been found.

But, they didn't define a lower bound on the size of an acceptable consensus set. What is the lower bound on the size of an acceptable consensus set?

Answer (score 1):

See discussion in sections 4 and 5 of [Torr's paper on MLESAC](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/publications/2000/Torr00/torr00.pdf). Hartley's slides from an old tutorial have the [table of interest at page 33](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~hartley/Papers/CVPR99-tutorial/tut_4up.pdf)